# What is the best way to store a generic List in a Map value?

Tags: java, list, dataframe, object, hashmap

I am doing a University assignment about developing a Dataframe library (we are supposed to import the data from files such as csv, json and txt). The data structure I chose is `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>` where the key represents a column label and the value (List) is the column values storage. When the program reads a file the first row goes through a filter which determines which kind of Object it is (Integer, String...) in order to add the data in that way (`list.add(new Integer(2))` for example) but I'm not sure if it is the best way to proceed because the program is supposed to make some operations as well such as sort values (comparator), query (predicate)... Take into account every column can contain a different data type.

I also thought about using `ArrayList<String>` instead and transforming the values when necessary but would not be too optimal and I prefer asking you first.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Example:

LatD    LatM    LatS    NS  LonD    LonM    LonS    EW  City    State

41      5      59       N   80  39  0   W   Youngstown   OH

Assignment document: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Saqiw23vQk7Yoh2csmuH2adcktNzDmjP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In my opinion, if you are certain that the files are containing only a single type of data (String, Integer, or Boolean, etc) then passing them through a filter and storing them in different types of ArrayList would be a better approach since you'll be processing them. And if you are not certain then just to avoid any runtime exc I would suggest you use simply List<String>.

Comment: Every column can contain a different data type. I'm editing the post with an example.

Comment: Yes of course. I meant whether each column has the same data type or not. But anyway It is really a question of design choice. Either way is fine as long as you are able to process the data further. I'd wait for answers coming from a bit more experienced persons.

Comment: Appreciated. You don't think using List<Object> would be a good approach? Asking because I'm still not too sure about the operations part:

sort: return the values of a column in the DataFrame following a certain order
df.sort(column, comparator)
query: return all elements where a label value fulfills a certain condition.

Comment: The assignment document helps a lot.  For anyone not wanting to read the assignment, their assignment is basically to create a spreadsheet data store.  Each cell can be a `String`, value (`int` or `double`), date, timestamp, or anything else I'm forgetting.  Sorting will be interesting to implement as you have to determine first that all the cells involved have the same cell data type, determine the data type sort, perform the sort, and write the cells back to the spreadsheet.  I'd say use `List<Object>` and be prepared to write lots and lots of `instanceof` code.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about your assignment, I'd consider creating a `Cell` class that specifies the value, type, and format of a spreadsheet cell, along with the `int` column and `int` row of the location of that cell in the spreadsheet.  Then I'd create a `Sheet` class that contains a `Map` of coordinate, `Cell` instances.  Finally, I'd create a `Spreadsheet` class that contains a `List` of `Sheet` instances.

Comment: Much appreciated but I would rather go for the `List<Object>` solution cause I have +50% of the assignment done already (was still pretty unsure about which data structure to use that's why I came here). On the other hand I will definitely mention your solution during the assignment interview (with credit ofc) since seems like a really good approach but from what I gathered the teacher emphasizes a lot on using column labels as identifiers. One more thing... Would you filter while storing the data in the `List<Object>` so every column has the proper data type elements after importing the file?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc (I forgot to mention you)

Comment: Based on my reading of the assignment, you have to translate the column headers to `int` values and vice versa.  The advantage of using a `Cell` structure is you create a sparse matrix.  Saves on storage.  I'd identify the object value type when reading the input files.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using [Guava's Multimap](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-multimap) instead of constructing Map with List values yourself.

On the other hand I would think about the design. Is the number of columns always the same and you know upfront what values are there? If the answer is yes, how about creating your custom value object with named fields of concrete types? Something like this sample below and implement some Comparators etc if required.

```
public class ValueRow {
    private Integer LatD;
    ...
    private String City;
    private String State;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but we can just use Collections data structures as far as I know. Also, the number of rows, columns, data types... Are dynamic that's why I need a generic structure. I'm adding the assignment's document to the post if want to know more.